# connecting thingsboard with backend

Tags: backend, mqtt, iot, thingsboard

How do you integrate the thingsboard IoT platform with a backend?

My special case is that users are using an app to control the state of different devices. The backend then writes into the devices attributes mqtt state. As the backend does a whole lot of stuff like authorization, authentication and others, I would like to restrict access to the devices for only the backend requests. This means that the backend must have some kind of "write" permission for all devices (throughout different customers).

Is the backend some kind of special device that has no ACL and no customer assigned or is there any other way I would do that? I saw that there is a REST API (https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/rest-api/), but using JWT token that expire feels wrong here.

Edit: I'm using the community edition

Answer (score 1):

Thingsboard provides some REST clients. I've used the Python one before and it's okay. [See here](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/python-rest-client/)

Main downside is that you need to provide user credentials with sufficient permissions to perform your desired actions. For example you could create a user called 'Backend' with very restricted permissions, and use the credentials in your backend code.